# Multi Friend Inviter for event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to bring up same multi friend selector but for an event?

I use this to select friends for an app invite:

```
FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: "An invite to compete',
            title: 'App Name'
        }, requestCallback);
```

Is there something similar to invite friends to an event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed is of a facebook dialog, you can find all of the available dialogs in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/). If you read that, you'll notice that there's no dialog to invite friends to events.

Using the graph api you can invite users to events, but those users need to be users of your app. If your users grant the app with create_event permission then you can invite them.
If they grant you with the rsvp_event permission then you can set them as attending, maybe or declined. (more here: [Event object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/))